# ZEND currency symbol is displaying 1

Tags: zend-framework

I'm using zend currency to display the currency based on locale.  When I use the following code the symbol gets replaced by 1 instead of simply being removed:

$currency = new Zend_Currency($locale);
$currency->setFormat(array('symbol' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL));

What normally gets returned is this: € 2.500,01
but after the "setFormat" call I'm getting this: 1 2.500,01

I don't want the "1 " in there.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the wrong option in setFormat. You need to set `display` to `Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL`. Like this:

```
$c = new Zend_Currency();
$c->setFormat(array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL));
echo $c->toCurrency(2500.01);
```

Which outputs

```
2,500.01
```

The way you are currently doing it is literally setting the symbol to 1 because that's what the constant NO_SYMBOL evaluates to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the ZF tutorial page for this. It looks like it will set a person in the right direction: [zend currency tutorial page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.currency.description.html)