# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Currency' not found

Tags: zend-currency

I am new to Zend.

Now, I am trying to print/format numbers as per my locale, however when I do this

```
$c = new Zend_Currency();
$c->setFormat(array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL));
echo $c->toCurrency(2500.01);
```

returns error.

I have checked this:

[ZEND currency symbol is displaying 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158698/zend-currency-symbol-is-displaying-1)

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are facing this issue because Zend library (Zend_Currency class) is not loading on page.

Comment: Yes, it is missing. I believe by default it should be there with ZF2 application.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the below class**

```
use Magento\Framework\Currency\Data\Currency as CurrencyData

$price = (float) $currencyObj->format($price, ['display' => CurrencyData::NO_SYMBOL], false);
```